# Is there any increase in legendary drop rate with the True Vault Hunter mode or the Vault Hunter's Relic?

Tags: borderlands-2

#### True Vault Hunter Mode

I heard it gives better and more loot, so does that mean legendary?

#### Vault Hunter's Relic

Says it increases rare drop rates, legendaries are rare, too... (heh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Vault Hunter's Relic

It has a very minor effect on legendary drop rates, that you're probably better off using another relic. It only affects white (common) and non-white drop rates (and not legendary drop rates, specifically).

From this [somethingawful.com forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140723034621/http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3504490&pagenumber=133&perpage=40#post408051645) by user, gibbed:

> So I just investigated the Vault Hunter Relic data.
>
> It modifies two attributes:
>
> GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_RareWeightModifier: +0.05
> GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_CommonWeightModifier: -0.06
>
> [Let's set them to +100.00 and -100.00!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6jIf.jpg)
> [image]
>
> Net result: I have not seen a single white weapon drop, greens drop,
> seen a few blues. Nothing else.
>
> So, what I can gauge from this, is that it shifts a 5% of your chance
> for whites into non-whites. Doesn't touch anything else. Very low
> impact, perhaps bordering on useless.

#### True Vault Hunter Mode

> Some of differences in True Vault Hunter Mode as opposed to Normal
> mode are:
> ...
>
> - **Better Loot**: Due to the nature of difficulty increase and the fact the game becomes more difficult, in True Vault Hunter Mode there
>   is a higher chance of enemies dropping better loot and chest also will
>   contain better loot.
> - **Better Loot more frequently**: Enemies in True Vault Hunter Mode will be have a higher percentage chance of dropping better loot as
>   they have more health and are more difficult to defeat.

<sup>Source: [Borderlands wiki, "True Vault Hunter Mode" article](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/True_Vault_Hunter_Mode)</sup>

Comment: There is also [a big crowdsourcing project](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/18r7ip/crowd_sourcing_project_v3_legendary_drop_rate/) on Reddit, where guys keep track of drop rates. Many sets are non-representative (below 100 runs), and crowdsourcing is unreliable by itself, but the results are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In first run, the relic helps you get some greens. However, as your level closes in on 50, and due to exponential increases in level powers, the color of weaponry becomes less important compared the level of the weaponry.  IE: a level 53 white weapon is better than a green 52 weapon.  Also, the relic basically becomes worthless very early on when you come across better relics more suited to your character (cooldown times, more ammo, etc).  Much like the season passes, it was basically an enticement item to sucker folks into ordering/buying.  IE: the expectation of what it could due lured folks in more than what the item actually could do.  "We're offering a special loot bonus item if you preorder or get mechromancer kit!"  "ZOMG!  AMAZING!"  (use item...find out it's completely worthless). Like most games, it's a gimick item to sucker folks in while not really giving them anything special.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a difference with the relic. When I didn't have it I rarely saw orange items; but now I have it I have more purple and orange gear than I know what to do with! It's a lot better if you have more players with the relic; so instead of 5% it's more like 10 or 20%. In any case an increase is an increase. I just think people are over thinking it.

Answer (score -1):

Not always true if you go to a regular boss that usually drops white or green. It will make way better chances to get a rare or legendary weapon. In my opinion, you should go try my theory out because I'm still in regular mode with my 35 Krieg. If there is some boost after any thing like a better chance of yellow other than farming, tell me.