# Drop rate stack increase?

Tags: borderlands-2

There are a lot of factors with drop rates in Borderlands 2, I was wondering: Does the drop rate for legendary items (or any better colored item) increase when in TVHM or in UVHM?

And if it does increase, would say, all four players in a game have the Vault Hunter's Relic, would it it's 5% chance of dropping rare items stack? Increasing the already increased drop rates when in harder modes?

Comment: You might want to check [this out](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112819/is-there-any-increase-in-legendary-drop-rate-with-the-true-vault-hunter-mode-or?rq=1). Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Twilight Sparkle Woahhh, sorrry, I didn't see that my question was already answered. :P Hahaha damn u Twilight